# Mocha-Jenkins Integration with Bash

Tags: node.js, bash, jenkins, mocha.js

I am using Mocha Programmatically to run tests on Jenkins CI using Bash script.
The first problem is that mocha does not exit automatically after running code unless i add an extra function that is not included in the documentation

```
var mocha = require('mocha');

//  Initializing Mocha
var m = new mocha({
    ui: "tdd",
    reporter: "mocha-multi",
    reporterOptions: {
        json: "report.json",
        "good-mocha-html-reporter": "report.html"
    }
});

function init() {
    // Adding files to tests
    m.files.push("test/test" + process.argv[2] + ".js");
    // Exiting test
    var runner = m.run(function(failures){
        process.on('exit', function () {
            process.exit(failures);
        });
    });

   // If i don't add this extra function the mocha process stuck
   // after running tests and does not exit properly  
    runner.on('end',function(foo){
        process.exit(foo);
    });
}

init();
```

The second problem is that when i add the test case in a bash file for Jenkins and run it. it dies not pass the correct exit code and the build will not fail even if the test case is failed to run

Here is the sample mocha-jshint test i am running

```
'use strict';
var jshint = require('mocha-jshint');

jshint({
    "title" : "jsHint - Code Quality"
});
```

Here is the Jenkins-build script for running tests

```
#!/bin/bash
node test.js JShint
```

The main bash runner file for Jenkins which looks for error codes

```
/usr/bin/ssh -p$SSH_PORT_NODE $NODE_HOST "cd $NODE_HOME; ./jenkins-build.sh"
echo $?
```

it always returns 0 exit status even if i add echo $? after each tests in jenkins-build.sh file. it returns 0 exit status even if the mocha process exit with 1 status i-e failures

Someone please guide me in solving these issues

Comment: Why are you running Mocha programmatically? Why don't you just invoke it from the command line?

Comment: I am running iit programmatically because its integrated i slack as well and we have lots of test cases with command line parameters and also there is a boot script on the root of the project so the main file at root runs all test cases that it receives as an argument.